# Get TID of thread running on CPU

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Is it possible to get the TID of the thread that is currently running on a logical core, such as logical core 0? This is easy to do in kernel space, but I am not sure how to get the thread information from userspace.

Comment: This information is not usually exposed as it could lead to all kinds of security issues. As far as the kernel is concerned, this is not the business of a user-space process. If you really wanted, you could make a kernel extension that creates a file you can read where this information is dumped out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information what is running on which core with `hwloc-ps` (require the `hwloc` package). For example, `hwloc-ps -a -t -l -e` gives you which threads of which process runs on which PU (ie. logical core). The provided information are the name of the thread and the SPID (certainly what you call a TID). You can get additional information by looking in `/proc/TARGET_PROCESS_PID/task/TARGET_THREAD_SPID/`. This last operation requires additional privileges (for obviously security reasons) though `hwloc-ps` apparently do not require advanced privileges.

Answer (score 0):

IDK the answer to that question, but it's unlikely that the answer will be useful to you in any case.

If you can get the information at all (@Jérôme Richard thinks you *can* get it), then what will you do with it? Something like this?

```c
int core_of_interest;
pid_t thread_of_interest;
...
if (thread_on_core(core_of_interest) == thread_of_interest) {
    do_interesting_thing();
}
```

That code won't reliably work. The problem is, by the time `do_interesting_thing()` was called there's no guarantee that the thread running on the `core_of_interest` still is the same thread that was running at the moment when you asked. All you really know is which thread was running on that core at some instant in time between when you asked and when the answer was returned. But with a preemptive scheduler running, which thread is running on which core can change at any time.

Comment: I agree but I would like this information so I can debug a program performance issue. I am seeing a thread block for 10+ ms at a time and its kernel stack indicates that it context switched to something else. The machine is otherwise idle so I suspect the thread it is switching to might be some sort of library thread or even the idle thread, but it is hard to say.

Comment: @JackHumphries, Sure. And so maybe Jérôme's answer is the one you should accept. But, it's possible that somebody else might find your question and these answers, and I am speaking to them as well as to you.